# Mapping UK Postcodes to Geographic boundaries for plotting

Tags: python, heatmap, folium, choropleth

I have a dataframe with a (UK) postcode column, and a count column, e.g.

```py
postcode  count
SW1W0NY   10
PO167GZ   22
GU167HF   15
L18JQ     38
```

I wish to create a heatmap of this data using `folium`, where the counts are aggregated as per larger (e.g. county-level) geographic polygons.

There are several [online resources](https://www.freemaptools.com/download-uk-postcode-lat-lng.htm) which map postcodes to lat/long, but is there any python library or resource which maps postcodes to larger UK geographic regions (e.g. county level)?

Comment: There is [`geopandas`](https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gallery/create_geopandas_from_pandas.html). I'm not sure if there are UK county maps, though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Office of National Statistics has such mapping files:

- from [Post Code to LSOA](https://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/search?collection=Dataset&sort=name&tags=all(LUP_PCD_OA_LSOA_MSOA_LAD))
- from [LSOA to UTLA](https://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/search?collection=Dataset&sort=name&tags=all(LUP_LSOA_UTLA))
- and from UTLA to [corresponding geometric boundary files](https://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/search?collection=Dataset&sort=name&tags=all(BDY_CTYUA)) (UTLA codes are equivalent to CTYUA codes)

Note that the mappings and codes are version/year specific, and may not be cross-compatible.